# How do I get flash messaging working with Laravel Breeze, inertia and vue3?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, inertiajs

I've followed several examples on this, including the laracasts video on flash messaging, but for whatever reason, I can never get the data passed to load into the props. Here's what I have:

```
In HandleInertiaRequests.php:
'flash' => function () use ($request) {
        return [
            'success' => $request->session()->get('success'),
            'error' => $request->session()->get('error'),
        ];


From a controller:
...
$page->save();
return redirect('/admin/pages')->with('success', 'Page created successfully');
```

And when I save a page, I check the vue dev tools and find this:

[image]

I also find it interesting that when the page is given a full page reload on a route that has with(...) data, that data populates a prop with the name passed to with, but even that doesn't allow the middleware to fill the flash props, and it (strangely) creates a new prop at 'page.props.success', with 'page.props.flash.success' still remaining null.

Comment: Weirdly, I've got the components working using "page.props.flash...", but my vue devtools are showing those values as null. I'm confused by this. A friend of mine spun it up and his devtools showed the props populated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you making sure to pass the flash method to the return statement?

In the `HandleInertiaRequests.php` middleware you should add the flash function to the array_merge function like this:

```
return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
'flash' => function () use ($request) {
            return [
                'success' => $request->session()->get('success'),
                'error' => $request->session()->get('error'),
            ];
        },
]
```

or save the flash in a variable like `$data` and pass it to the `array_merge` method.